# Place some text (bold) lower

Tags: css

I would like to place my bold text (Thierry) some pixels lower...

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <b>Thierry</b>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Something like (doesn't work):

```
.editor-field b
{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It depends what else is on the page. Margin-top will work in most cases yes, but if other items are in the way it will not. Please make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: relative` sounds like the most interesting way:

```
.editor-field b
{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGWZ8/)

`position: relative` is nice because it reserves the same space in the document flow as before, and moves the element freely inside the document. One side effect is that any elements below it will not move away - elements might overlap. You'll have to see whether that is okay for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could displace it using the position.

```
.editor-field b
{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

That should work.